# Do I need to implement my own QAbstractTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, inheritance, abstract-class

I found this question: [How to change the background color for a QTreeView Header (aka QHeaderView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342649/how-to-change-the-background-color-for-a-qtreeview-header-aka-qheaderview)

**I want to be able to set the color for each header section. So the question seen above seems to be my solution!**

The solution says "**the easiest way** to do that is probably to derive a new model from QAbstractItemModel or another model class and reimplement the headerData()". I went and [looked at the Qt source tree for QTableWidget, QTableModel, QTableWidgetItem](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp)... these classes are supposedly "default models" so I thought they would be a good example and then I would go implement my own QAbstractTableModel.

The 3 files I saw are a whopping 3300 lines of code. That is definitely NOT "the easiest way" IMO!!!

I would like the functionality of QTableWidget but then I want to add the following ability:

- horizontalHeader.setSectionColor(index,color)
- verticalHeader.setSectionColor(index,color)

**Do I really need to inherit/implement QAbstractTableModel if all I want is to change the color of a section header?**

---

Update:

I am not using my own custom view and model classes. I am using [the convenience class QTableWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/model-view-programming.html#id-d08af867-bcf4-47c1-9851-fe7f10edea96) right now (it is called a convenience class b/c it implements the view and model). The function [`headerData()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) is part of the model. The [model class, QTableModel,](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp) is not accessible via Qt lib/headers so I can't inherit from it.

---

Update:

I tried creating a new item with background brush `QBrush(QColor(Qt::red))` and then setting the table's header with the new item (using `QTableWidget::setHorizontalHeaderItem(int column, QTableWidgetItem *item)`. I also tried inheriting `QTableWidgetItem` and overriding the virtual `data()` method with:

```
QVariant HeaderItem::data(int role) const
{
    if(role==Qt::BackgroundRole) {
        return QVariant(QBrush(QColor(Qt::red)));
    } else if(role==Qt::ForegroundRole) {
        return QVariant(QBrush(QColor(Qt::green)));
    } else {
        return QTableWidgetItem::data(role);
    }
}
```

I can change the header sections foreground. But when I try to change the header's background brush... nothing happens... it's like the QTableWidgetItem's background brush that I set for the header section is ignored.

Comment: Why can't you just override headerData method of the model used by your view? What is your exact setup, i.e. which widget and which model classes do you use?

Comment: @chalup I updated the question for you.

Comment: Maybe provide custom QHeaderView would do the trick... I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating model with custom headerData() from scratch create subclass of [QTableWidgetItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QTableWidgetItem.html) with desired implementation of [QTableWidgetItem::data()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#data) and use the instances of this class for [QTableWidget::setHorizontalHeaderItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem).